# Strings from text file not equating in if statement with program strings in Python

Tags: python, file, text

I read some strings which are usernames from a file into my Python program, then these strings are tested in if statement to see if they are equal to the value entered in the Entry box, but the value from the Entry box and the file even are not equating in the if statement even when I saw they were the same.

Comment: Did you strip `'\n'` from the strings fetched from file?

Comment: Yes, i used the regex, re.subn() method to strip '\n' and also to match spaces in the begining and ends of the file strings...i dont know wats wrong as it looked strange when i tested the type() of the two strings and they are the same!! And still not equating!!

Comment: Please post a sample of your code.

Comment: I'm so so so sorry everyone that has expected my codes back. I got it working already, bt i dont get to b on d internet frequently so i'v nt bn able to tel u guys its solved.. Sory mods, and all ye gurus. . I'm sory again! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you debug your code, I mean, you must have to debug and see that it returns the Entry box value or not, if it returns value, then check what value it return.

Comment: I printed the gotten value from the Entry box and the file side by side and they were the same, but stil wont work!! But guys, hope this isnt a problem of character encoding? The textfile is in ascii

Answer (score 0):

You're probably dealing with whitespace (either in the data you read from the file, or from your user input.) Call [`.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a string.

Comment: I've stripped with strip() and also with regex, stil not working. Okay, i'm gonna post the code now...but you guys can still help meanwhile...thanks